# failed to run distributed inception in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to try run tensorflow in its distributed mode. As a test programm I chose googles inception. 
When running it with some workers, one of them always gets the error. The other worker processes are still running but do not produce any result.

```
RROR:tensorflow:==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'report_uninitialized_variables/boolean_mask/Gather:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
It was originally created here:
```

Because of my setting at university I'm only able to run tensorflow 1.3.0. I already tried different branches of the inception repository (e.g. master, 1.5.0) but always get this error.

log of worker3 which gets the error. (a bit shortened to get it posted here)

```
[31m[1m WORKER CUDA Devices: 2 [0m
INFO:tensorflow:PS hosts are: ['tensorsrv1:12000']
INFO:tensorflow:Worker hosts are: ['tensorsrv1:12001', 'tensorsrv1:12002', 'tensorsrv1:12003', 'tensorsrv1:12004']
2018-06-20 12:15:11.189503: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:84:00.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.10GiB
2018-06-20 12:15:11.189700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2018-06-20 12:15:11.189763: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2018-06-20 12:15:11.189830: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0)
MPI Environment initialised. Process id: 3 Total processes: 5 || Hostname: tensorsrv1 
D0620 12:15:11.507919397   18686 env_linux.c:77]             Warning: insecure environment read function 'getenv' used
2018-06-20 12:15:11.516434: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> tensorsrv1:12000}
2018-06-20 12:15:11.516569: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> tensorsrv1:12001, 1 -> tensorsrv1:12002, 2 -> localhost:12003, 3 -> tensorsrv1:12004}
2018-06-20 12:15:11.516871: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:12003
INFO:tensorflow:SyncReplicasV2: replicas_to_aggregate=4; total_num_replicas=4
INFO:tensorflow:2018-06-20 12:16:44.998266 Supervisor
2018-06-20 12:16:47.722197: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:998] Start master session c18a779f191ac2a4 with config: allow_soft_placement: true
INFO:tensorflow:Waiting for model to be ready.  Ready_for_local_init_op:  None, ready: Variables not initialized: global_step, conv0/weights, conv0/BatchNorm/beta, conv0/BatchNorm/moving_mean, conv0/BatchNorm/moving_variance, [...]
[...]
2018-06-20 12:17:23.765818: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:998] Start master session bb98c90a9044da55 with config: allow_soft_placement: true
INFO:tensorflow:Starting queue runners.
INFO:tensorflow:Started 3 queues for processing input data.
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 2: 2018-06-20 12:17:48.049978: step 0, loss = 13.13(1.5 examples/sec; 21.359  sec/batch)
INFO:tensorflow:Worker 2: 2018-06-20 12:17:50.677927: step 0, loss = 13.09(12.2 examples/sec; 2.628  sec/batch)
ERROR:tensorflow:==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'report_uninitialized_variables/boolean_mask/Gather:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
It was originally created here:
    ['File "/shared/tensorflow//models/research/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 66, in <module>\n    tf.app.run()', 'File "/sw/tensorflow/1.3.0-Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run\n    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))', 'File "/shared/tensorflow//models/research/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 62, in main\n    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)', 'File "/shared/tensorflow//models/research/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 222, in train\n    apply_gradients_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)', 'File "/sw/tensorflow/1.3.0-Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py", line 257, in apply_gradients\n    variables.global_variables())', 'File "/sw/tensorflow/1.3.0-Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 175, in wrapped\n    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))', 'File "/sw/tensorflow/1.3.0-Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 144, in _add_should_use_warning\n    wrapped = TFShouldUseWarningWrapper(x)', 'File "/sw/tensorflow/1.3.0-Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 101, in __init__\n    stack = [s.strip() for s in traceback.format_stack()]']
==================================
```

The full logs of every process can be found at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/t6yhnDn7) because they are to long for this post.

I started it with

```
python  bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=32 \
--data_dir="${DATA_DIR}" \
 --job_name="${JOB_NAME}" \
--task_id="${TASK_IDX}" \
--ps_hosts="${PS_STR}" \
--worker_hosts="${WORKER_STR}" \
--protocol="grpc+mpi" \
--max_steps=100
```